# Defining expression in theano

Tags: python, theano

I have a question about theano library.
Suppose I have two matrices: `a_ij` and `b_ij` that respectively have shapes `[n, m1]` and `[n, m2]`.

I want to define an expression which gives tensor `c` of shape `[n, m1, m2]`:

```
c_ijk = a_ij * b_ik
```

(pay attention that there is no sum, so this is not a dot product).
Of course I can do this calculation in a loop, but I want theano to calculate derivatives for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theano tensors broadcast exactly like numpy arrays. All you have to do is

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

n, m1, m2  = 10, 20, 30
A = T.fmatrix()
B = T.fmatrix()

C = A.reshape((n, m1, 1)) * B.reshape((n, 1, m2))

func_C = theano.function([A, B], C)

a = rng.randn(n, m1).astype(np.float32)
b = rng.randn(n, m2).astype(np.float32)

r1 = func_C(a, b)
r2 = np.einsum("ij, ik -> ijk", a, b)
assert np.sqrt(((r1 - r2) ** 2).sum()) < 1e-5
```

Where the definition of `C` is the crucial part. This can also be done with dynamic shapes, but this answer stays within your framework.

Comment: That was really easy, shame on me. Thank you :)